# vDSP.DCT unwraps to nil

Tags: swift, accelerate-framework, null-pointer, dct, vdsp

When I execute this line of code:

`self.forwardDCTSetup = vDSP.DCT(count: 40, transformType: vDSP.DCTTransformType.II)!`

I get:

`Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`

I am following this tutorial almost exactly: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/accelerate/signal_extraction_from_noise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `vDSP.DCT` follows the same rules as `vDSP_DCT_CreateSetup` with regard to length / count:

```
The supported values are Length = f * 2**n, where f is 1, 3, 5, or 15 and n is at least 4.
```

See: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/accelerate/1449930-vdsp_dct_createsetup

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Do you know why this constraint exists? The 2**n part makes sense but `f` doesn't.

Comment: @Syllabear: The DCT and DFT routines are implemented with a classic (but vectorized) FFT for the power-of-two lengths and the [prime-factor-algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime-factor_FFT_algorithm) (PFA) for other lengths. The PFA is implemented efficiently by hard-coding permutations into the load and store operations and hard-coding “butterfly” calculations, and this was done for factors of 3 and 5, which also supports their product, 15. Supporting higher factors runs into problems with the number of available processor registers and the number of cases that must be hard-coded.